# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied in taskDefinition.addToTaskRolePolicy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

The policy 's3:Put*' can work but s3:List*' can not work and show error message

[image]

```
    taskDefinition.addToTaskRolePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ["ecs:Poll",
    "ecs:StartTask",
    "ecs:StopTask",
    "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
    "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
    "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
    "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
    "ecs:DescribeContainerInstances",
    "ecs:Submit*",
    "ecs:DescribeTasks",
    's3:GetBuck*',
    's3:List*',
    's3:GetBucketVersioning',
    's3:PutBucketVersioning',
    's3:Abort*',
    's3:DeleteObj*',
    's3:GetObj*',
    's3:PutObj*',
    's3:Replicate*',
    's3:Put*',] ,
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  resources: ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                  "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/upload/*"]
}));
```

I added all policies of S3, but it can not work and show the error message.

Are there any policies for this?